# PDF downloads won't open in IE or Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, pdf, download

I'm working on the content for a site that handles a lot of document downloads (.pdf, .docx, .pptx, etc). They are uploaded via a remote desktop connection to an ASP.NET site. I've noticed that some of the PDF documents will not open. After clicking on the link to get the document, the download will finish but the extension seems to be missing and the computer will not know how to open the file. It will tell me that Windows cannot open it, claim that the file type is "unknown," and ask if I want to search for the correct program to use.

I have the option to save the file and add a .pdf extension (and then it will open). However, this is not a great solution for potential users who aren't familiar with this process.

This has only happened in Chrome(v23) and IE9. I've tested on Mac and PC. Firefox downloads the PDFs just fine. All browsers have been updated. PDFs on my desktop open fine.

I have tried disabling/enabling all Adobe PDF related add-ons and plugins. I've re-installed Adobe Acrobat and Reader. I have played with the Acrobat and Reader Internet Options as described in a couple places online. So far, no luck and I am completely out of ideas.

Does anyone have any insight as to what is going on? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Always amazing how backwards MS-Windows is. Trying to determine a files type by insisting on an 'extension'... LOL -- but serious: you have a problem with the http headers you send. Take a look at a few examples from google and check the headers used against those you send. There probably is a difference. Alternatively publish the headers you send here...

Comment: Although I'm not familiar with http headers (I'm not a programmer), I ran web-sniffer for the issue area. Hopefully this is what you meant? It gave me a "Read timeout" and no results.

Comment: That result does not make sense. Aparently you did not sniff a successful download. Such a successful download is an http stream consisting of first headers, some `key:value` lines, then an empty line and then the payload, the pdf in this case. The leading headers tell the browser what to expect and how to handle it. If you cannot successfully dump that information from the network stream then have a try using a good browser that is capable of showing you that information. Currently I only know of the 'konqueror' browser capable of doind so. But learning network sniffing is a good idea.

Comment: I don't know much about ASP (I prefer PHP) but I could imaginge there is a feature in ASP that outputs headers sent whilst serving a request. Try dumping those to a log file maybe.

Comment: If I understood what you were talking about, I'm sure this would be the solution :) I'll run this past someone who is more knowledgeable than I am in this field. Thanks for the tips.